# SQL QUERY to select the month in a particular order like from mar to feb, apr to mar, nov to oct

Tags: sql

I have to write a query to select months in a particular order like from Mar to Feb, or Feb to Jan.  I can't use a stored procedure. I have to use SELECT and in the database the names of the months are stored like 'january', 'febrary', 'march' and so on...

While fetching the months I need only the first 3 characters.

result should be

```
jan 1
feb 2
mar 3
apr 4
may 5
jun 6
jul 7
aug 8
sep 9
oct 10
nov 11
dec 12
```

after using this query

```
Select distinct upper(convert(varchar(3),datename(MONTH,InvoiceDate))) as monthName,upper(convert(nvarchar,datepart(mm,InvoiceDate))) as 
    mon  
from OpenInvoiceDetails 
order by mon
```

i get

```
jan 1
oct 10
nov 11
dec 12
feb 2
mar 3
apr 4
may 5
jun 6
jul 7
aug 8
sep 9
```

Comment: what is your question ? I don't see any question mark in your post...also please post some of code that you have work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please take a little time to read the [FAQ] before too long.  At the moment, your question is unanswerable because you've not given us enough information.  You need to give us an outline schema for your table — table name (surprisingly often forgotten), column names for the important/relevant columns and their types, and preferably a few rows of data and your expected output.  Generally, though, you should store date values in DATE or similar types.  Also, the answer may vary by DBMS; it is a good idea to mention which DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a lot of assuming here, but something like this would work:

```
    Create Table Months
(
    DateColumn varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO Months

SELECT 'January' 
UNION
SELECT 'February'
UNION
SELECT 'March'
UNION
SELECT 'April'
UNION
SELECT'May' 
UNION
SELECT 'June' 
UNION
SELECT 'July' 
UNION
SELECT 'August'
UNION
SELECT 'September'
UNION
 SELECT'October' 
UNION
SELECT 'November'
UNION
SELECT 'December'

SELECT  DateColumn ,( CASE DateColumn
            WHEN 'January' THEN 1
            WHEN 'February' THEN 2
            WHEN 'March' THEN 3
            WHEN 'April' THEN 4
            WHEN 'May' THEN 5
            WHEN 'June' THEN 6
            WHEN 'July' THEN 7
            WHEN 'August' THEN 8
            WHEN 'September' THEN 9
            WHEN 'October' THEN 10
            WHEN 'November' THEN 11
            WHEN 'December' THEN 12
          END ) as [Month]
From Months
Order by Month
```

Gives you this:

```
January 1
February    2
March   3
April   4
May 5
June    6
July    7
August  8
September   9
October 10
November    11
December    12
```

Order by Month Desc:

```
December    12
November    11
October 10
September   9
August  8
July    7
June    6
May 5
April   4
March   3
February    2
January 1
```

Comment: Order by Month Desc to get months in reverse order

Comment: is there something like sorting in sql.... i want result to be jan 1 , feb 2 , mar 3  apr 4, may 5,jun 6,jul 7,aug 8,sep 9,oct 10,nov 11,dec 12 but after executing the query which i have posted  i getjan 1 oct 10 nov 11 dec 12 feb 2 mar 3 apr 4 may 5 jun 6 jul 7 aug 8 sep 9

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to be optimal, but it should resolve the invalid column name.

```
Select distinct upper(convert(varchar(3),datename(MONTH,InvoiceDate))) as monthName
,upper(convert(nvarchar,datepart(mm,InvoiceDate))) as mon 
from 
 OpenInvoiceDetails 
order by Len(convert(nvarchar,datepart(mm,InvoiceDate))),
convert(nvarchar,datepart(mm,InvoiceDate))
```

Comment: it gives invalid column name 'mon'

Comment: doesnot work ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to change your `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY Cast(mon as int)
```

Good luck.

Comment: Try using ORDER BY Month(InvoiceDate) -- Dependsd on your RDBMS...  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this query

```
    Select distinct
    upper(convert(varchar(3),datename(MONTH,daterecieved))) as monthName,
    datepart(mm,daterecieved)  as mon 
    from Donations 
    order by mon
```

AND

```
    Select distinct
    upper(convert(varchar(3),datename(MONTH,InvoiceDate))) as monthName,
    Cast(upper(convert(nvarchar,datepart(mm,InvoiceDate)))  as int) as mon 
    from OpenInvoiceDetails 
    order by Cast(upper(convert(nvarchar,datepart(mm,daterecieved)))  as int)
```

Comment: it gives invalid column name 'mon'

Comment: doesnot work ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: i will prefer 1st query over second